# How to block access via computer browsers

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

l have created a PWA and I can install it on mobile phones. But it is also accessible via chrome on windows for example.

Is there any way to prevent access to this application via computer browser?

I'm running the application in 21.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What harm can a computer do?

Comment: None, but I created the application for mobile use, and don't want the users to be messing with this version, when there is a version specifically made for bigger screens. On this application some objects won't render correctly because of that.

Comment: I wouldn't do much really. At most the screen will be broken. An ideal solution, given that you have both versions, is to redirect to each other if the "wrong" client is detected, or to put a banner suggesting that if not possible. It's not really infrequent to see webpages broken on mobile really, and I wouldn't be surprised to find the other way around.

Comment: And isn't the PWA still using an embedded web browser?